# Python Google Cloud Function Logging Severity and Duplicates

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-stackdriver

I'm working on a simple Google Cloud Function that runs in the Python runtime and I want some simple logging from the Python program to Stackdriver Logging.

Based on Google's startup guide, this should be straighforward
https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/setup/python

I set up a simple test function to isolate the logging issues I'm seeing

```
import google.cloud.logging

def logging_test_background(data, context):

    logging_client = google.cloud.logging.Client()
    logging_client.setup_logging()

    logging.info("This should be info")
    logging.debug("This should be debug")
    logging.warning("This should be warning")
    logging.error("This should be error")
```

In Stackdriver Logging everything gets jumbled.
[image]
 1. Info is duplicated as an Error
 2. Debug doesn't come through
 3. Warning is duplicated, but both are error logging level
 4. Error is duplicated

Is there something I'm missing in the configuration?

Answer (score 10):

You need to create your own logger and add the `google-cloud-logging` default handler to it:

```py
import logging

from flask import Flask
from google.cloud import logging as cloudlogging

log_client = cloudlogging.Client()
log_handler = log_client.get_default_handler()
cloud_logger = logging.getLogger("cloudLogger")
cloud_logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
cloud_logger.addHandler(log_handler)

def logging_test_background(data, context):
    cloud_logger.info("info")
    cloud_logger.warning("warn")
    cloud_logger.error("error")
    return 'OK'
```

Produces:

[image]

Comment: I tested this code exactly. It resolves the duplicates issue and info is coming through correctly, but warning is still coming through as error.

Comment: Is it possible to have the `execution_id` since it's useful to trace GCF instances.

Comment: I echo what @ajgriese said. Warnings are still coming through as errors. Did you find a solution?

Comment: What about debug?

Comment: @Tjorriemorrie debug-level messages didn't come through most probably because the default level is info (which is higher priority then debug)

Comment: @ajgriese Apparently this is a known issue: https://github.com/googleapis/python-logging/issues/91 They say that they don't have the resources to fix this, so we would need to wait for a while.