# Writing python logs to Google Cloud inside a Cloud Function

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-logging

I've been unable to send logs to Google Cloud Logging inside a Cloud Function using the Cloud Logging client library for Python. The function runs without errors but I can't see the logs on Google Cloud.

Is there something I am missing any configuration settings on the Cloud Function?

I created a small Cloud Function, based on [Google's Guide](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/setup/python), to isolate the problem:

**main.py**

```py
from flask import Flask
import logging
import google.cloud.logging

client = google.cloud.logging.Client()
client.get_default_handler()
client.setup_logging()

def log_test(request):
    logging.info("info")
    logging.warning("warning")
    logging.error("error")
    return 'OK'
```

**requirements.txt**

```
Flask==1.0.2
google-cloud-logging==2.3.1
```

Function is deployed with:
`gcloud functions deploy log_test --runtime python38 --trigger-http --allow-unauthenticated`

The function runs without error but the Log Explorer does not show the written logs:
[image: Log Explorer]

If I run the same code locally with the environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` the logs are properly sent.

I also tried creating a logger as https://stackoverflow.com/a/56810898/154618 but got the same behavior.

Comment: Check that the service account assigned to Cloud Functions has a Cloud Logging role.

Comment: This is a similar issue with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65525189/

Comment: I also tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/56810898/154618 using the workaround on my previous comment and it works as expected using `python 3.7`.

Comment: Using `python 3.7` solved it @RiccoD. Thanks!